Dynamic Line Chart with Selection and Its Higher L1 & L2 Categories
Thanks to anyone who takes a look.
I've been frustrated for a few days, trying many ways and checking numerous posts, parameter (not working).
Model Detail:
I'm working with a 3-tiered data model and have a measure called [_Line Chart] for a dynamic line chart.
[_Line Chart]
to use Table - Master2 as a control to ensure that all Tier 1 & Tier 2 numbers can be counted starting from Tier3's start date.
Table - Master is the original import data
Tiers : Here's how the tiers should display:

Tier 1: Always shown with its calculated number.
Tier 2: Appears as a single line when selected.
Tier 3: Also appears as a single line when selected.

Expect Result:
There will be 2 slicers for Tier 2 and Tier 3.
Users can select Tier 2 from Slicer 1, then select the item they would like to see the trend for under Tier 3.
The line chart should show 4 lines:

2 from Tier 1 (assumed as United States-level numbers),
1 from Tier 2 (assumed as States-level numbers),
1 from Tier 3 (assumed as City-level numbers).

Thanks in advance.
Sample Model
